# How can I receive an account id during the OAuth process? (Nest Api Oauth)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase, nest-api

Regarding the use of the Nest API with firebase client.

In order to keep firebase connections to a minimum (due to limit restrictions), is there any way allowing me to receive a Nest unique identifier (account correlation) for an account after the oauth process?
So that this way I can have multiple users using only one firebase connections per Nest account.

The state query parameter won't be of any help in here since I can't know which user belongs to which Nest account.

Thank you,
Miguel